# C preprocessor substitution and concatenation

Tags: c++, concatenation, c-preprocessor, stringification

I am trying to define

```
#define tokenBits 32
typedef inttokenBits_t Token;
typedef int#tokenBits#_t Token;
typedef int##tokenBits##_t Token;
typedef int###tokenBits###_t Token;
const tokenBase=numeric_limits<Token>::min()
```

How should I define it in order to get

```
typedef int32_t Token;
```

Where is exactly written the way of functioning of `#define` (I found texts both none gives the full vision).

Comment: The # and ## operators can only be used in #define preprocessor statements, not in normal code.

Comment: those macros are really bad, any reason to use your `define`, and not pure typedefs ?

Comment: I want to change just in one point the size of the Token.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b,c) a ## b ## c
#define MYINT_TYPE(tokenBits) CONCAT(int, tokenBits, _t)

typedef MYINT_TYPE(tokenBits) Token;
```

Comment: @chris I find it easy to read and clear. What are the downsides to it?

Comment: @Jefffrey, Just brings up the question of why is it there (it does have a purpose), except I'm too tired and it is actually required because `tokenBits` is a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Use a macro:

```
#define BIT_AWARE_TYPEDEF(bitness, type, result) typedef type##bitness##_t result;
```

Less configurability:

```
#define TOKEN(bitness) typedef int##bitness##_t Token;
```

Answer (score 0):

use template:

```
template <std::size_t N> struct sized_int;

template<> struct sized_int<32> { using type = int32_t; };
template<> struct sized_int<64> { using type = int64_t; };

#define tokenBits 32

using Token = typename sized_int<tokenBits>::type;
```